# Movie about a spaceship travelling to a distant planet, only to discover that a newer ship, designed and launched later, has gotten there first

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

A few years ago I saw a movie, the title of which I just can't remember.

It was a movie about a crew on a spaceship travelling a long time to a distant planet or system to check on something, or to bring life to this planet.

I also remember: When they arrived OR when some problems occur they found a ship with their same name but with the number "2", like Voyager (fictional name) 1 and 2, and they could not understand why there was a second ship around.

The explanation was that, DURING their travel period, scientists developed a new faster drive, so that a new ship launched later on the same mission arrived at the planet before the first one.

I might remember that this is some known paradox.  If you go on a long space journey, the scientific progress that's made can actually make a new ship reach the same destination faster, despite being launched later.

I'm dying to remember this movie - I google all the way down and couldn't find it.

Edit:
It was a live action movie and I think it was streamed via Amazon / Netflix. It was an international movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: I think the paradox referred to is the "Wait Calculation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_travel#Wait_calculation If an interstellar trip will take more than 50 years it is better to wait until more scientific progress has been made

Comment: Was this a live-action movie or animated?  Did you watch it on a streaming service, a video service like YouTube, or was it actually broadcast?

Comment: Oh, and is the slower ship a generation ship (people live all the years of the voyage, have children who then become the crew and so on) or a sleeper ship where (almost) everybody is in some kind of stasis so they don't age?

Comment: I remember reading a book with a similar plot maybe 50 years ago. One line I remember from near the end was "How could we have forgotton human progress?!"

Comment: @FlaStorm32 That's a line from Van Vogt's "Far Centaurus" (*Astounding*, January 1944).

Comment: Something similar happens in Heinlein's *Time for the Stars* -- the torchships are sent out, almost touching lightspeed at turnover, but maintaining instantaneous telepathic communication with Earth.  After five or six stops, the protagonist's ship is met by Earth humans who have overtaken them with a new "fountain ship" (presumably faster than light).

Comment: I can't think of any films where the ['lightspeed leapfrog' trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog) is a part of the plot

Comment: Recording the following points from answers and edits possibly posted by the OP:  2-4 years ago; it was a sleeper ship; "it was very similar to Voyager from Allen Steele."  (Note I don't get the last one.)

Comment: Had it been animated, it could be the anime [space fantasia 2001 nights](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Nights) , which has a similar storyline